# Loop to populate separate emails generates emails within same email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to generate Outlook emails based on data from two Excel sheets.

- "Sheet1": (recipient information)
- "Config": (references to attachment links, subject lines, sentences of the email body, etc.)

The code creates embedded images in the middle of the body with sentences above/below the image.

**Issue**:
The code opens all content in a single Outlook email.
I need to loop through all the row items in "column A" and populate separate emails.

I researched online but couldn't find an example with inline images and looping.

Code Sample:

```
Sub create_emails()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim reportsRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range
Dim SendID
Dim Subject
Dim Body
Dim olMail As Object
Dim fileattach, ccid, wimage, sig, mimage, msub, wsub, cname, cemail, sdate, mname, mfrom, wfrom As String
Dim s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 As String
Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(0)
Set Doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
Dim oAttach As Object
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set reportsRange = Range("A2", Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

'configuration references
s1 = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c14").Value
s2 = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c15").Value
s3 = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c16").Value
s4 = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c17").Value
s5 = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c18").Value
fileattach = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c3").Value
ccid = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c4").Value
mfrom = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c5").Value
wfrom = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c8").Value
mimage = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c6").Value
wimage = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c9").Value
msub = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c7").Value
wsub = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c10").Value
sig = wb.Sheets("Config").Range("c11").Value

'recipient references
mname = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value
sdate = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("d2").Value
cname = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c2").Value
cemail = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").Value

For Each xlCell In reportsRange
    If xlCell.Value <> "" Then
        With olMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = mfrom
            .To = SendID
            .CC = ccid
            .Subject = msub
            .Attachments.Add mimage, olByValue, 0
            .Attachments.Add sig, olByValue, 0
            .Attachments.Add fileattach
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<font color=""#1a5276"" face=""AmplitudeTF""> Hi " & xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value _
              & ",<br><br>We have " & xlCell.Offset(0, 2).Value & " joining your team on " & xlCell.Offset(0, 3).Value & "!<br><br>" _
              & s1 & "<br><br>" & s2 & "<br>" _
              & "<img src='cid:mon.png'" & "width='800' height='500'><br><br>" _
              & s3 & "</font><br><font face=""AmplitudeTF"" color=""#7d6608"">" & s4 _
              & "</font><font face=""AmplitudeTF"" color=""#1a5276""><br><br>Regards,<br>" _
              & "<img src='cid:gps.png'" & "<br>" _
              & s5 & "</font></span>"
            .display
        End With
    End If
Next xlCell
Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You only create a new email once - `Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(0)` is outside your loop, but should be inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code "opens all content in a single outlook email" because only one email is created.

Move `Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(0)` *inside* the `For Each` loop to create a new email each time `xlCell` is not blank.